# Making a Modal Appear OnClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm struggling with getting a modal to appear `onClick()`. I have a function within a component that adds players to an existing list when clicking on `Add Player`. The button is rendered separately in a `renderAddButton()` function, which passes `onAddButtonClick()` as a prop.

I would like for the user to be able to input the player's name in a form within a modal before it is added to the list, right now the code outputs a `Player` + `index` as the name of the player.

```
    function onAddButtonClick() {
        setItems((prev) => {

            const newItems = [...prev];

            newItems.push({
                name: `Player ${newItems.length + 1}`,
                teamId: currentTeam[0].teamId
            });

            playersStore.push({
                name: `Player ${newItems.length + 1}`,
                teamId: currentTeam[0].teamId
            });

            return newItems;
        });
    }
```

I have this form which I want to represent in the modal:

```
export const PlayerForm = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <input type='string' id='playerId' name='playerName' defaultValue='0' />
                <input
                    type='number'
                    id='playerGoals'
                    name='totalGoals'
                    defaultValue='0'
                    min='1'
                    max='5'
                />
                <input
                    type='number'
                    id='playerGoals'
                    name='playerGoalPercentage'
                    defaultValue='0'
                    min='1'
                    max='5'
                />
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};
```

How do I trigger the modal from inside `onAddButtonClick()`?

Comment: first u need to create the codes for bootstrap-model.

Comment: @clattenburg cake lmk if that answer helps you out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implement modals using the [react-bootstrap framework](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/).

From the component that I want to display the modal from, I will create a handler that will govern the component's ability to `show` the modal based on the bool I set in `state`. Typically from the `parent` component this show handler would look like this:

```
setShow = () => {
  this.setState({ show: !this.state.show });
};
```

As seen in the example this handles a `state` attribute called `show` which is what dictates whether or not the modal gets to display in app.

Below is the implementation of the modal I would use as a child component to the parent component where it would reside and where I would pass the `state` attribute which I called `show` that dictates with `true` or `false` whether or not to display the modal:

```
<ExampleModal
  show={this.state.show}
  setShow={this.setShow}
  activeRecord={this.state.activeRecord}
  activePrimaryAccountId={this.state.activePrimaryAccountId}
  userAccessRole={this.props.userAccessRole}
/>
```

I pass the necessary details that the modal needs to display as `props` that I get from the the parent component's `state` attributes. The most important being the `show` attributes to include the `setShow` function which I use in the child component (the modal itself) to update `state` in the parent component to close the modal when the time comes also.

In the `ExampleModal` component I start off with declaring `state` with the following attributes already loaded from `props`:

```
this.state = {
  show: this.props.show,
  ...

}
```

I then use a handler that takes advantage of the `setShow` function passed down to the child component in `props` as shown:

```
handleClose = () => this.props.setShow(false);
```

In the modal component there is a button that uses this handler in its `onClick()` synthetic event to trigger the closing of the modal after it has rendered to the browser.

Conversely in the parent component, your button will use the `onClick()` synthetic event to trigger a call that would be implemented something like this in the button to open the modal:

```
onClick={this.setShow(true)}
```

I reuse that process in all of my modals in React.js, hope that helps. The trick here is using `componentDidUpdate()` or `useEffect()` (if you're using React Hooks) effectively to make sure you have the right data loaded in `state` in the parent component so that you can pass it into the props of the child component at the right time. The `<ExampleModal />` I gave you should give you enough of a clue.